# Discord.js messageCreate event handler not fetching command from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I've been following the discord.js guide (https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files) to try and learn how to use event handlers instead of having everything in the main JavaScript file, but when i made the switch, it stopped working. I checked what was going wrong, and this line in my messageCreate event handler is returning "undefined": `const command = message.client.prefixCommands.get(message.name);`

Here is my code for my main JavaScript file:

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.prefixCommands = new Collection();
const prefixCommandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/prefix_commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of prefixCommandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/prefix_commands/${file}`);
    client.prefixCommands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.login(token);
```

and for the messageCreate event handler:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'messageCreate',
    async execute(message) {
        const prefix = "!";
        
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const command = message.client.prefixCommands.get(message.name);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(message);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await message.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    },
};
```

Here is an example of an interactionCreate handler I have that works, which is mostly formatted the same:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    
        if (!command) return;
    
        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    },
};
```

The interactionCreate event handler works, but the messageCreate event handler does not, despite them being formatted in almost exactly the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

and you should check this first.

If you need your bot to receive messages (MESSAGE_CREATE - "messageCreate" in discord.js), you need the Guilds and GuildMessages intent, plus the MessageContent privileged intent to receive the content, attachments, embeds and components fields of the message.